# Is there a function in R to take all occurances of a name from a column within a data frame and assign them to a new data frame

Tags: r

I have a Data set with many columns and rows, in am narrowing down the data as to get a specific answer.
I want to remove all occurances of Names within a column.
i know you can do this for columns that are Numbers, buy removing number below or over a certain number

for example:
data =

ID Name sport

1. ted  football
2. tom  football
3. tim  hockey
4. tod  Track
5. ben  football

for numbers i would

removen <- data[data$ID < 2, ]

removen =

ID  Name  Sport

3. tim  hockey
4. tod  Track
5. ben  football

i want to assign

x <- c(all occurances of football)

so when i call x i would get

ID Name sport

1. ted  football
2. tom  football
3. ben  football

Thank you in advance and sorry for the formating.

Comment: `result <- data[data$Sport == "football", ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grepl`

```
x <- subset(df, grepl('football', sport))
x

  ID Name    sport
1  1  ted football
2  2  tom football
5  5  ben football
```

Comment: Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset)] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. I got this error.

Comment: @JamieMcGrath What are you doing? Just copy paste my code. Where there is `df` replace it with the variable name that contains your data. I do not know how you named your data

Comment: Easy, sorry i am new.